# Как я могу кучу ифов преобразовать в ООП

Tags: c#, ооп

У меня есть бот который анализирует текст, который ему прислали.
И в итоге я написал такую кашу из if

```
if (message.Message.Type != MessageType.Text)
{
   LogAndDeleteUser(in message);
   string ret = Random_Say();
   gBot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Message.Chat.Id, ret + ". Введи текстовый запрос");
   i = 0;
}
else if (message.Message.Text.ToLower().Equals("/start"))
{
   LogAndDeleteUser(in message);
   Keyboard_help(ref message);

}
else if (message.Message.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("/List") || message.Message.Text.Contains(""))
{
   LogAndDeleteUser(in message); 
   new ListGroups().Cours(ref keyboard, ref message);
}
else if ((message.Message.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("/group") || message.Message.Text.Contains("‍")) && i == 0)
{
   LogAndDeleteUser(in message); 
   Rassilka.Add(message.Message.Chat.Id, true);
}
else if (message.Message.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("/me") || message.Message.Text.Contains(""))
{
  LogAndDeleteUser(in message);
  Me(message);
  Console.WriteLine(message.Message.Chat.Type);
}
```

Как мне это все превратить в пправильное ООП?
Я думал сделать интерфейс, и наследование от него, но мне кажется это будет не правильно + я хочу гибкости, а как тут сделать гибкость, если привязка к тексту идет?

Comment: А почему не использовали switch? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Comment: Так я хочу от этого вообще избавиться, и ооп сделать. Да и свич пробовал, и это как минимум не получилось реализовать `message.Message.Type != MessageType.Text`

Comment: На самом деле хороший вопрос, подожду ответа с вами=)

Comment: Создать базовый клас Command or BotCommand, абстрактный метод Select or HasCurrentCommand (над неймингом надо подумать), Action метод. И наследники  у которых будет Selectors (текст команды и вариации) и свой екшн. Общий BotCommandProcessor, у которого будет список всех типизированных команд и который будет бегаь по ним, вызывать   HasCurrentCommand  и Action , если HasCurrentCommand  (..) = true. Еще паттерн фабрика можно глянуть.

Comment: Вообще, для этого можно посмотреть исходники какой-то консольной утилиты

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Например, `Cours(..., ref message)` - тут использован модификатор `ref`, значит `message` может быть присвоена новая ссылка?

Comment: На это можно не обращать внимание, потому что я могу это убрать

Comment: @Ssss Спасибо, теперь осталось понять это все, а это случайно не паттерн какой-то?

Comment: Создать базовый класс Command и от него унаследовать классы конкретных команд-обработчиков. Парсер команд вынести в отдельное место - можно на базе switch, можно при помощи готовых библиотек типа https://habr.com/en/company/microsoft/blog/542340/  . See also: https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/command

Comment: _На это можно не обращать внимание_ - тогда весь код на помойку. Что значит "не обращать внимание", если этот момент критически важен? Ведь ссылка меняется.

Comment: Предлагаю просто сократить и упростить код за счёт выделения общих частей. `LogAndDeleteUser(in message);` повторяется в каждой ветке - убираем эту строку из них и пишем один раз перед `if`. Делаем переменную `string text = message.Message.Text` и далее используем её. Код сразу прилично сокращается.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ООП - это объекты, а значит первое, что нужно сделать, это разбить код на отдельные составляющие. Я не буду переписывать именно ваш код, покажу лишь небольшой пример:

1. Сделаем простой класс одной команды, допустим, так:

   ```
    public class Command
    {
        public Action Action { get; init; }
        private string[] triggers { get; init; }

        public Command(Action action, params string[] triggers)
            => (Action, this.triggers) = (action, triggers);

        public bool HasTrigger(string trigger)
            => triggers.Contains(trigger);
    }
   ```

   - `Action` - это то, что будет выполняться.
   - `triggers` - так, как "триггеров", которые могут вызвать команду у нас может быть несколько, это массив.
   - `HasTrigger` - проверяем, есть ли указанный триггер в команде или нет.
2. Далее давайте сделаем простой класс `Commands`, он будет отвечать за хранение команд и их выдачу/вызов:

   ```
    public class Commands
    {
        private List<Command> commands = new();

        public void Register(Command command)
            => commands.Add(command);

        public void Invoke(string trigger)
        {
            var command = commands.FirstOrDefault(x => x.HasTrigger(trigger));

            if (command is not null)
            {
                command.Action.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                NotFound(trigger);
            }

            // логгирование?
        }

        private void NotFound(string trigger) 
            => Console.WriteLine($"Команда {trigger} не распознана!");
    }
   ```

   Тут как видите тоже все весьма просто:

   - `commands` - некая коллекция, в которую мы будем добавлять команды (регистрировать их).
   - `Register` - простой метод, который добавит `Command` в коллекцию.
   - `Invoke` - метод вызова нужной команды.
   - `NotFound` - пример простого вывода сообщения о том, что команда не найдена.

   Можете спросить "а зачем тут отдельные методы, почему мы не можем сделать коллекцию команд публичной и добавлять сразу в нее?", ответ очень прост - контроль. Когда у нас есть отдельный метод, мы может сделать, к примеру проверку нужную нам, или можем добавить логгирование, да много чего еще.
3. Все основное у нас готово, давайте соберем тестовый макет:

   ```
    public class Time
    {
        public void SendTime()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private Commands commands = new();

        public Program()
        {
            commands.Register(new(SendMe, "/me", "/мне"));
            commands.Register(new(new Time().SendTime, "/time", "/время"));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Start();

        public void Start()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Команда: ");
                commands.Invoke(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }

        public void SendMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Отправили Me");
        }
    }
   ```

Вот вам и простой пример реализации команд, где вся логика сводится к вызову методов `.Register()` и `.Invoke()`. Заметьте, в примере я специально сделал класс `Time`, который наглядно показывает то, что команды могут быть где угодно в нашем проекте, а также то, что вся логика может быть (да и должна) разбита на отдельные методы/классы. Вам же тут остается переписать этот пример на тип `Message`, чтобы можно было в случае чего проверить тип, ну это я думаю не составит для вас труда.

Это конечно базовая демонстрация, тут нет много чего, например, передача параметров. Также стоит позаботиться о неких ограничениях, чтобы нельзя было любой метод регистрировать в качестве команды, сделать, например интерфейс, который будет четко помечать те классы, которые реализуют команду и на его основе уже дальше следовать.

Если проект весьма сложный, то регистрацию команд можно автоматизировать. Для этого многие используют атрибуты, по которым потом определяют является ли класс "командным" или нет, но это уже совсем другая история)

[image: Result]

Comment: @Houl Где именно? Если консоль, то она не поддерживает просто так символы, заменяя весь ввод на `?` (или аналог). Если в боте, то сравните то, что у вас приходит в сообщении с тем, что Вы регистрируете в качестве команды. Как видите, у меня используется `triggers.Contains(trigger);`, строгое соответствие с тем, что в коллекции `triggers`, то есть нечто такое идет `triggers[0] == ""`, только по всем элементам. Любой лишний символ даст тут как понимаете `false`.

Comment: Да все поправил уже, это у меня затупы были, поэтому не срабатывало